How can i put the CRON expression in a Function app parameter in the local.settings.json file?
I have a function app that I run and one of the functions is as follows:
    [Function("JobsTrigger")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("1,31 * * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] MyInfo myTimer)
    {
          <rest of the code>
    }

Now how can I put the CRON expression "1,31 * * * * *" in the local.settings.json file and when I deploy to put in the appsettings.json file ?
So in other words when the function app starts up I want to read that parameter setting from the appsettings.json file.

wouldn't you just manage that in the azure deployment pipeline variables? sorry what is the question? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

and can i run it every second cause i dont see the cron expression allowing seconds ?

no, minute is the smallest unit, but cron isn't meant for this. You will instead want to create a Task for that kind of operation.

You can define your CRON expression in local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "YourSchedule": "1,31 * * * * *"
  }
}

and then you should be able to reference it by name in your Azure Function:
[Function("JobsTrigger")]
public void Run([TimerTrigger("%YourSchedule%", RunOnStartup = true)] MyInfo myTimer)
{
    // <rest of the code>
}

